# How do I group regular expressions past the 9th backreference?

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-group

Ok so I am trying to group past the 9th backreference in notepad++. The wiki says that I can use group naming to go past the 9th reference. However, I can't seem to get the syntax right to do the match. I am starting off with just two groups to make it simple.

**Sample Data**

```
1000,1000
```

**Regex.**

```
(?'a'[0-9]*),([0-9]*)
```

According to the [docs](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions#Groups) I need to do the following.

```
(?<some name>...), (?'some name'...),(?(some name)...)
Names this group some name.
```

However, the result is that it can't find my text. Any suggestions?

Comment: ouch...9 back-references? Are you sure you aren't maybe over-complicating something?

Comment: Not at all, I am restoring database data, and using notepad++ to format the insert statements.

Comment: In that case, why not just generate the insert statements via a scripting language?

Comment: I guess I could, but I have visited this prior with Notepad++ and tried to get past the 9th reference and couldn't do it. So now I am just trying to make it happen.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can simply reference groups > 9 in the same way as those < 10

i.e $10 is the tenth group.

For (naive) example:
String:

> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

Regex find:

> (?:a)(b)(c)(d)(e)(f)(g)(h)(i)(j)(k)(l)(m)(n)(o)(p)

Replace:

> $10

Result:

> kqrstuvwxyz

My test was performed in Notepad++ v6.1.2 and gave the result I expected.

Update: This still works as of v7.5.6

---

SarcasticSully resurrected this to ask the question:

> "What if you want to replace with the 1st group followed by the character '0'?"

To do this change the replace to:

> $1\x30

Which is replacing with group 1 and the hex character `30` - which is a `0` in ascii.

Comment: Ok that did it, where is it documented in the wiki to use a $ sign for groups and how did you even figure it out??

Comment: +1 Wow, I thought I tried everything (like \10, \g10, \g{10}), but forgot the simple $ alternative.

Comment: @meanbunny - Good question(s)! 1) [N++ Regex Substitutions](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions#Substitutions) 2) I didn't figure it out from the wiki, weirdly. I just _did it_... Can't explain why! Guess I lucked out.

Comment: But what if you want to replace with the 1st group followed by the character '0'?

Comment: @SarcasticSully - Updated my answer to cover your edge case

Comment: @BunjiquoBianco I just tested that. It still uses the 10th group. I'm not sure what I was suggesting is possible in javascript.

Comment: Ok, no idea for javascript. This is for Notepad++

Answer (score 4):

A very belated answer to help others who land here from Google (as I did).  Named backreferences in notepad++ substitutions look like this:  `$+{name}`.  For whatever reason.

There's a deviation from standard regex gotcha here, though... named backreferences are also given numbers.  In standard regex, if you have `(.*)(?<name> & )(.*)`, you'd replace with `$1${name}$2` to get the exact same line you started with.  In notepad++, you would have to use `$1$+{name}$3`.

**Example:**  I needed to clean up a Visual Studio .sln file for mismatched configurations.  The text I needed to replace looked like this:

```
    {CDDB12FE-885F-4FB7-9724-1A4279573DE5}.Dev|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {CDDB12FE-885F-4FB7-9724-1A4279573DE5}.Dev|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    {CDDB12FE-885F-4FB7-9724-1A4279573DE5}.Dev|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {CDDB12FE-885F-4FB7-9724-1A4279573DE5}.Dev|x64.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    {CDDB12FE-885F-4FB7-9724-1A4279573DE5}.Dev|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {CDDB12FE-885F-4FB7-9724-1A4279573DE5}.Dev|x86.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    {CDDB12FE-885F-4FB7-9724-1A4279573DE5}.QA|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
    {CDDB12FE-885F-4FB7-9724-1A4279573DE5}.QA|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    {CDDB12FE-885F-4FB7-9724-1A4279573DE5}.QA|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
    {CDDB12FE-885F-4FB7-9724-1A4279573DE5}.QA|x64.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    {CDDB12FE-885F-4FB7-9724-1A4279573DE5}.QA|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
    {CDDB12FE-885F-4FB7-9724-1A4279573DE5}.QA|x86.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
```

My search RegEx:

```
  ^(\s*\{[^}]*\}\.)(?<config>[a-zA-Z0-9]+\|[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)*(\..+=\s*)(.*)$
```

My replacement RegEx:

```
  $1$+{config}$3$+{config}
```

The result:

```
    {CDDB12FE-885F-4FB7-9724-1A4279573DE5}.Dev|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Dev|Any CPU
    {CDDB12FE-885F-4FB7-9724-1A4279573DE5}.Dev|Any CPU.Build.0 = Dev|Any CPU
    {CDDB12FE-885F-4FB7-9724-1A4279573DE5}.Dev|x64.ActiveCfg = Dev|x64
    {CDDB12FE-885F-4FB7-9724-1A4279573DE5}.Dev|x64.Build.0 = Dev|x64
    {CDDB12FE-885F-4FB7-9724-1A4279573DE5}.Dev|x86.ActiveCfg = Dev|x86
    {CDDB12FE-885F-4FB7-9724-1A4279573DE5}.Dev|x86.Build.0 = Dev|x86
    {CDDB12FE-885F-4FB7-9724-1A4279573DE5}.QA|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = QA|Any CPU
    {CDDB12FE-885F-4FB7-9724-1A4279573DE5}.QA|Any CPU.Build.0 = QA|Any CPU
    {CDDB12FE-885F-4FB7-9724-1A4279573DE5}.QA|x64.ActiveCfg = QA|x64
    {CDDB12FE-885F-4FB7-9724-1A4279573DE5}.QA|x64.Build.0 = QA|x64
    {CDDB12FE-885F-4FB7-9724-1A4279573DE5}.QA|x86.ActiveCfg = QA|x86
    {CDDB12FE-885F-4FB7-9724-1A4279573DE5}.QA|x86.Build.0 = QA|x86
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

OK, matching is no problem, your example matches for me in the current Notepad++. This is an important point. **To use PCRE regex in Notepad++, you need a Version >= 6.0**.

The other point is, where do you want to use the backreference? I can use named backreferences without problems **within the regex**, but not in the replacement string.

means

```
(?'a'[0-9]*),([0-9]*),\g{a}
```

will match

```
1000,1001,1000
```

But I don't know a way to use named groups or groups > 9 in the replacement string.

Do you really need more than 9 backreferences in the replacement string? If you just need more than 9 groups, but not all of them in the replacement, then make the groups you don't need to reuse **non-capturing groups**, by adding a `?:` at the start of the group.

```
(?:[0-9]*),([0-9]*),(?:[0-9]*),([0-9]*)
           group 1             group 2
```

Comment: I think I could have made this work also. This is a great answer as well. When I saw yours, I started thinking about group nesting which would have also worked in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

The usual syntax of referencing groups with \x will interpret \10 as a reference to group 1 followed by a 0.

You need to use instead the alternative syntax of $x with $10.

The question here is for Notepad++, but if you ever have to do this in Bash, don't forget to escape the expression as \$10

*Note : Some people seem to doubt there's ever any reason to have 10 groups.*

*I have a simple one, I wanted to rename a group of files named 
<name_start>*DDMMYYYY_TIME_DDMMYYYY_TIME*<name_end> as <name_start>*YYYYMMDD_TIME_YYYYMMDD_TIME*<name_end>, 
and ended with replacing my input matches with : 
rename "\1" "\2\5\4\3_\6_\9\8\7_$10" since name_start and name_end were not always constant.*

Comment: Note that in Bash you have to escape the `$` so it looks like `\$10`.

Comment: But the context here is Notepad++ ??